# Azure communication service phone call not working

Tags: azure-communication-services

I have an issue when initiating a phone call via Azure Communication Service on ReactJS.

I have already tried the C# console app with the `Azure.Communication.CallingServer` nuget.
Instruction here ([Azure/azure-sdk-for-net](https://azure-sdk-for-net/sdk/communication/Azure.Communication.CallingServer%20at%20a20e269162fa88a43e5ba0e5bb28f2e76c74a484%20%C2%B7%20Azure/azure-sdk-for-net%20%C2%B7%20GitHub)).

But both of them have the same issue, after the call is made, it disconnected immediately.

Code example:

```js
const callAgent: CallAgent;
const callClient = new CallClient();
callClient.createCallAgent(tokenCredential).then((callAgent: CallAgent) => {
  callAgent = callAgent;
});
const callOption: AddPhoneNumberOptions = { alternateCallerId: {phoneNumber: '+142xxxxx62'}};
const pCaller: PhoneNumberIdentifier = { phoneNumber: '+84xxxxxxx47' };
const pCallee: PhoneNumberIdentifier = { phoneNumber: '+66xxxxxxx18' };
const groupCall = callAgent.startCall([pCaller, pCallee], callOption);
subscribeToCall(groupCall, false);
```

Note: I can make Audio call and Video call via `8:acs:cc`, just have issue with phone number calling

I am running this application in a google chrome browser on a windows computer which I believe is supported and I am using the latest SDK so I'm not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks